# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS not updated

Tags: sql-server-2005

I notice this weird behavior where I change the column type from ntext to nvarchar(max) and in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS the data_type remains ntext ...

Is there something i must execute for the metadata to be refreshed?

I'm on sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get this behaviour on tables on SQL2005 (I just tested)

Is this for a view based on a table definition that has changed? If so

```
exec sp_refreshsqlmodule 'schema.ViewName'
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I did that .. but I end up restarting sql server and it was all fine now.